# JHipster: how add sidebar menù

Tags: jhipster

Can anyone please help with on how to add a sidebar to Hipster home page? I need to add a left side menu to my Jhipster app and no idea on how to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is too broad and leads to opinionated answers.
Anyway, you could try [PrimeNG](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/) and [this JHipster module](https://github.com/sudheerj/generator-jhipster-primeng) and you'll get more than just a side menu.

Comment: Ok, I will be more accurate. I need a sidebar menu that can read from a json file a father- children structure data. I'll take a look the links you sent me. Thanks.

Comment: I have tried to use PrimeNG and Jhipster module but does not work. I'm using Angular4 and PrimeNG is for Angular 2 perharp

Comment: What does mean "does not work"? Please provide details. PrimeNG supports angular 4 for sure.